# Limit of $\frac{x^y-y^x}{x^x-y^y} $ while $x\to y$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$$\lim_{x\to y}\frac{x^y-y^x}{x^x-y^y} $$
I've tried L'Hospital and [this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3Ey+%28%28x%5Ey-y%5Ex%29%2F%28x%5Ex-y%5Ey%29%29) Both doesn't tends to work. Please help someone.

Comment: What part of the answer Alpha gives do you consider to be incorrect?

Comment: The answer is right but I can't get to it with or without using L'Hospital.

Comment: I think you should retry doing L hospital, remember you differentiate only in respect of $x$. It should work

Comment: I did that but the part x^x in denominator is giving the problem. Also after doing L'Hospital I have not been able to reach to the simplified answer. @clark

Comment: $x^x= e^{x \ln x}$

Comment: See also: [Limit of $\frac{x^y-y^x}{x^x-y^y} $ while $x\to y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480445).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'Hôspital's rule works:
$$\lim_{x \to y} \frac{x^y-y^x}{x^x-y^y} = \lim_{x \to y} \frac{yx^{y-1}-y^x \ln y}{x^x \ln x +x^x} = \frac{1-\ln y}{1+\ln y}.$$