# Finding the value of the given limit!

Tags: limits

> The value of $\lim_{x \to y} \cfrac{x^y - y^x}{x^x - y^y} $ is $\dots$
>
> $(a) \ \cfrac{1 - \log x}{1+\log x} \qquad (b) \ \cfrac{1-\log y}{1+\log y} \qquad (c) \ \cfrac{\log x - \log y}{\log x + \log y} \qquad (d) \ \text{None of these}$

Not sure about this one. Have tried to think about using L'H rule but seems like a dumb idea. Taking $\log$ on both sides may or may not help. Am not sure. As the terms will be of the form $\log (a-b)$ in numerator and denominator, which I suppose are hard to simplify. Any hint will be appreciated too.

Comment: Guess what ? Taylor again gives the answer !!!

Comment: If you can explain how @ClaudeLeibovici ...!

Comment: A minor hint: since $x$ is a "running" variable, the result cannot depend on it. This rules out (a) and (c).

Comment: What did you exactly mean by $x$ is a running variable, @AlexM. ?

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{t\to a}f(t)$. So the limit cannot depend on $x$.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thanks @egreg !

Comment: See also: [Limit of $\frac{x^y-y^x}{x^x-y^y} $ while $x\to y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480445), 
[How to find the limit $x=\lim_{a\to{b}}{\frac{a^b-b^a}{a^a-b^b}}$ without using L'Hopital's rule?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888518)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $y = x + h.$  we will compute the following using the fact $\ln(1+h) = h+\cdots.$

$$\begin{align}\ln(y^y)&=(x+h)\ln(x+h) = (x+h)\left(\ln x ++h/x+\cdots\right)\\&=x\ln x+h(1+\ln x)+\cdots\\
\ln(x^y) &= (x+h)\ln x\\
\ln(y^x) &=x\ln y=x(\ln x + h/x + \cdots) = x\ln x + h+ \cdots\end{align}$$

from these we get, $$y^y - x^x= e^{x\ln x}e^{h(1+\ln x)} = x^x\left(1 + h(1+\ln x)+\cdots\right) -x^x = hx^x(1+\ln x)+\cdots\\
y^x-x^y = e^{x\ln x}e^h - e^{x\ln x}e^{h\ln x}=x^x\left(1+h + \cdots -(1+h\ln x+ \cdots) = hx^x(1-\ln x)\right)+\cdots$$

therefore $$\lim_{y \to x}\frac{x^y - y^x}{x^x - y^y} =\frac{1-\ln x}{1+\ln x} .$$

Comment: I was just typing the same when your answer came ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Well, it was the limit for $x\to y$… Not that this invalidates the proof, but maybe you can fix it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, good to see you. maclaurin is my man.

Comment: @abel. And Taylor is my love !

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ and $g$ are two functions, then $(f^g)' = gf^{g-1}f'+f^g (\log f) g'$. Now take $f=g=x$ and apply l'Hospital's theorem.

Comment: Wasn't aware about that formula. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KushashwaRaviShrimali: It is a very useful one. You prove it by noting that $f^g = \mathbb{e}^{g \log f}$ and then deriving as usual, since the variable is now only in the exponent.